# How to update a parameter in query (python + bigquery)

Tags: python, loops, google-bigquery

I am trying to make multiple calls to export a large data set form Bigquery into csv, via python. (e.g. 0-10000th row, 10001th-20000th row etc). But I am not sure how to set a dynamic param correctly. i.e. keep updating a and b.

The reason why I need to put the query into a loop is because the dataset is too big for a one time extraction.

```
a = 0 
b = 10000

while a <= max(counts):     #i.e. counts = 7165920

    query = """
    SELECT *
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.ethereum_blockchain.blocks`
    limit @a, @b 
    """
    params = [
    bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter('a', 'INT', a),
    bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter('b', 'INT', b) ]

    query_job = client.query(query)
    export_file = open("output.csv","a")
    output = csv.writer(export_file, lineterminator='\n')
    for rows in query_job:
        output.writerow(rows)
    export_file.close()
    a = b +1
    b = b+b
```

For a small data set without using a loop, I am able to get the output without any params (I just limit to 10 but that is for a single pull). 
But when I tried the above method, I keep getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

#### Suggestion of another approach

**To export a table**

As you want to export the whole content of the table as a CSV, I would advise you to use an ExtractJob. It is meant to send the content of a table to Google Cloud Storage, as a CSV or JSON. Here's [a nice example](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data) from the docs:

```
destination_uri = 'gs://{}/{}'.format(bucket_name, 'shakespeare.csv')
dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id, project=project)
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)

extract_job = client.extract_table(
    table_ref,
    destination_uri,
    # Location must match that of the source table.
    location='US')  # API request
extract_job.result()  # Waits for job to complete.

print('Exported {}:{}.{} to {}'.format(
    project, dataset_id, table_id, destination_uri))
```

**For a query**

Pandas has a [read_gbq](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_gbq.html) function to load the result of a query in a DataFrame. If the result of the query fits in memory, you could use this then call to_csv() on the resulting DataFrame. Be sure to install the pandas-gbq package to do this.

If the query result is too big, add a destination to your QueryJobConfig, so it writes to Google Cloud Storage.

#### Answer to your question

You could simply use string formatting:

```
query = """
SELECT *
FROM `bigquery-public-data.ethereum_blockchain.blocks`
WHERE some_column = {}
LIMIT {}
"""

query_job = client.query(query.format(desired_value, number_lines))
```

(This places desired_value in the WHERE and number_lines in the LIMIT)

If you want to use the scalar query parameters you'll have to create a job config:

```
my_config = bigquery.job.QueryJobConfig()
my_config.query_parameters = params # this is the list of ScalarQueryParameter's
client.query(query, job_config=my_config)
```

Comment: hey! Thank you for answering, will explore the above suggestion.

Comment: hey i did manage to get it to work but i realised its because I cant put params at limit. Have to be in the where clause? So i numbered my rows instead.

Comment: @rspyxxx woops sorry I assumed you were sure about this syntax but turns out it doesn't make any sense to BigQuery. You definitely should focus on the alternate solutions proposed as first part of my answer (e.g export table to a CSV in Google Cloud Storage then download this CSV to your machine)